# Merge csv file side by side using batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv, merge

I have a very basic batch command to merge csv files together, however I need them merging so that the columns are side by side not continuing on. There will always be the same number of records on each file. This is the basic code I have so far:

```
COPY File1.csv + File2.csv CombinedFile.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< File2.csv (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (File1.csv) do (
      set /P line2=
      echo %%a,!line2!
   )
) > CombinedFile.csv
```