# Batch - Zigzag merging with two files

Tags: windows, batch-file, merge

I would like to make a zigzag merging of two text files as following.
I have two files in input:

```
file1.txt
A
A
A
```

and

```
file2.txt
B
B
B
```

I would like to have as output:

```
output.txt
A
B
A
B
A
B
```

Can anyone please tell me which may be the simpliest way to do this in batch (I'm forced to use this native windows langage).
Thank you!

Comment: Can we assume that the line count in both files is equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that the number of lines in both files is equal, this will work:

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE NUL>output.txt
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET linecount=0

FOR /F %%i IN (file1.txt) DO SET /a linecount=!linecount!+1

FOR /L %%n IN (1,1,!linecount!) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "file1.txt"') DO (
        IF "%%a"=="%%n" SET lineA=%%b
    )
    FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "file2.txt"') DO (
        IF "%%a"=="%%n" SET lineB=%%b
    )
    ECHO !lineA! >> output.txt
    ECHO !lineB! >> output.txt
)
```

The first FOR loop simply count the lines in file1.txt. The second loop iterates over the number of lines. Both internal loops execute the command `findstr /n .* "fileX.txt"` on file1.txt and file2.txt. The /n parameter outputs the content of the file adding *:* at the beginning of each line. So we split each modified line with delimeter `:` and store everything after `:` if the line starts with the current line index which is incremented after each interation. So after n-th iteration of the "big" loop `!lineA!` contains contains the n-th line of the first file and `!lineB!` contains the n-th line of the second file and both lines are appended to output.txt.

Comment: Yes the number of lines is equal in both files. Many thanks, this works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your process is called *file merge* and the simplest way to achieve it is reading the second file via redirected input. This method even works with more than two input files, as described at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521799/combinining-multiple-text-files-into-one/14523100#14523100) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850167/solved-merge-several-csv-file-side-by-side-using-batch-file/28864990#28864990).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Second file will be read from redirected input
< fileB.txt (

   rem First file will be read via FOR /F
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (fileA.txt) do (
      echo %%a
      rem Read and write next line from second file
      set /P lineB=
      echo !lineB!
   )

rem Send result to output file
) > output.txt
```

Comment: You're welcome! Just a detail: check _the time_ that these solutions take to produce the result, specially if the input files are large...