# windows batch file combine csv in a folder by column

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I would like to create a windows batch file to combine a folder full of CSV's into one CSV file but by column, not at the end.

```
file1.csv
A, B
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6

...

fileN.csv
C, D
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6

results.csv
A, B, C, D
1, 2, 1, 2
3, 4, 3, 4
5, 6, 5, 6
```

All of the examples I have seen combine 2 files with a defined name, or a simple copy one after the other. I cannot find how to copy by column!

Comment: How many files must be combined?

Comment: And are they all the same length?

Comment: @aacini variable number of files

Comment: @ somethingDark, currently they are the same length but may be variable. does it make a difference?

Comment: @jme: More than 9 files? More than 81 files? PS - When programming in Batch files, all details are important and can make a huge difference!

Comment: @jme If your files have different numbers of lines then the columns will be jumbled.  The total length of any one line is limited as well, making those details important.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the solution I posted at [merge-several-csv-file-side-by-side-using-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850167/solved-merge-several-csv-file-side-by-side-using-batch-file/28864990#28864990) topic in order to merge several files selected via a wild-card (instead of files given in the parameters). This solution can process a "variable number of files", but just a maximum of 8 files can be merged into another one; if there are more than 8 files, several "merged files" will be created with up to 8 files each in "mergedFiles" folder. If you want to generate *one file* from more than 8 files, you must repeat the process with the files in "mergedFiles" folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem MergeFiles2.bat: Merge several files horizontally, version 2
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Get the list of files to merge into "file" array
set "num=0"
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set /A num+=1
   set "file[!num!]=%%a"
)

rem Merge files from the "file" array
set /A merge=0, last=0
if not exist mergedFiles\ md mergedFiles

:nextMerge
set /A merge+=1, first=last+1, last+=8
if %last% gtr %num% set last=%num%

rem Assemble the lists of redirections and SET /P commands for this merge
set "file1=!file[%first%]!"
echo/
echo The following files:
echo - %file1%
set /A first+=1
set "redirs="
set "commands="
set handle=2
for /L %%i in (%first%,1,%last%) do (
   echo - !file[%%i]!
   set /A handle+=1
   set "redirs=!redirs! !handle!<"!file[%%i]!" "
   set "commands=!commands! & set /P "line=^^!line^^!, " ^<^&!handle!"
)
if defined commands set "commands=!commands:~3!"
echo will be merged into:  mergedFiles\file%merge%.csv

rem First file in this merge is read with FOR /F command
rem The rest of files are read via standard handles, starting at # 3

%redirs% (
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file1%") do (
      rem Get a line from first file
      set "line=%%a"
      rem Write-Read lines from all files, excepting the last one
      %commands%
      rem Write the line from last file
      echo !line!
   )
) > mergedFiles\file%merge%.csv

if %last% lss %num% goto nextMerge
```