# How to move files using batch script from 1 directory to the another if the path of the files are mentioned in two different text files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two text files - **sample1.txt** and **sample2.txt** which contains path of moving the files from sample1 to sample2. To make it more clear. I have these two files:
**Sample1.txt**

> C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\ABC\New Text Document.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\ABC\sdfsdf .txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\XYZ\New Text Document.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\OPQ\asdasd.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\OPQ\New Text Document.txt

**Sample2.txt**

> C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Backup\New Text Document.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\ABC\Backup\sdfsdf .txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\XYZ\Backup\New Text Document.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\OPQ\Backup\asdasd.txt
>   C:\Users\borkarv\Desktop\Sample\OPQ\Backup\New Text Document.txt

I want to move all the files from sample1.txt to sample2.txt such that path1 from sample1.txt goes in path1 of sample2.txt and so on.

I tried to use two for loops for this but that creates a problem as the files get overwritted.

```
FOR /F "delims=/" %%x in (sample1.txt) DO ^
FOR /F "delims=/" %%y in (sample2.txt) DO ^
move "%%x" "%%y"
```

I was thinking of putting && in between the 2 for loops but that doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide examples of what filemoves would take place given your sample data

Comment: That be all text files  that are going to get moved. The text files might contain a lot of data though(the data is not arranged in a specific order)

Comment: So the question you should ask is: [How can two text files be read in parallel by a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38214874)

Comment: Thats right! The site was useful though I am still confused how they were used. I saw the comments and all but didnt understand. How can I move them?

Comment: You are making this harder than it has too be.  You don't need the second file.  If the only change is moving it to a sub folder named backup, then all you need is the first file.

Comment: How do I do that then?

Comment: Looking back at all the other questions you have asked about this same project you are working on, what you are doing makes absolutely no sense to me. It literally baffles me.

Comment: @Squashman that is 1 component.Cannot explain the whole thing. Thanks for your help so far though