# How to Find line in text file and export line number

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I am building a Username and Password function for a batch file, and I have the system to read from 2 text files, Uname and Pass, and find the usernames and passwords, but the system is pulling any password listed in Pass. How can I read the line the username is on, set the password to only accept the corresponding line in the Pass text file?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (Users.txt) DO IF '%uname%'=='%%x' goto AdmCont
rem FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (Pass.txt) DO IF '%code%'=='%%x' goto AdmCont
```

Comment: You could try using something like awk to find the relevant line, but I am sure there are some better ways

Comment: In batch files the single quote has no special meaning. To just check if the entered `%uname%` is present in the users.txt I'd use `for /f "delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "%uname%" user.txt') do set "LineNo=%%A"`. Then use a for /f with skip to start reading pass.txt from that line and compare with the entered `%code%`

Comment: So you are saying that if `Squashman` is on line 52 of the user file, the password is on line 52 of the password file?

Comment: @Squashman Yes, Exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how-can-two-text-files-be-read-in-parallel-by-a-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214874/how-can-two-text-files-be-read-in-parallel-by-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution:

```bat
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %A IN ('findstr /n "%uname%" Users.txt') do ( @set "number_of_line=%A" && @set "_uname=%B" )
```

Or, using `find` instead of `findstr` (quite complicated):

```bat
for /f "eol=- delims=[] tokens=1-2" %A IN ('find /n "%uname%" Users.txt') do ( @set "number_of_line=%A" && @set "_uname=%B" )
```

As in your post you have requested batch file code (you have double percent signs (`%%`)) you can **double the percent-signs of the variables**.

Let me explain my code:

In both two loops, we parse output of commands. You should know the command-output-format and why using `findstr` is much simpler.

## `findstr`

- We use `/n` option with `findstr` which tells it to `echo` the line that found string specified.
- After `/n` option, we specify string that should be searched in specified after file.
- After that, we specify the file we want to search the specified string.

The output will be:

```bat
%line_number%:%content_of_line%
```

So, we parse it saying:

- DON'T PARSE `:` symbol into token with `delims=:` option!
- Access the `line_number` with `%(%)A` and `content_of_line` with `%(%)B` using `tokens=1,2` option.
- Well known: specify variable letter add `IN`, then command to be parsed and set to variables number of line and its content.

## `find`

- We use `/n` option with `find` which tells it to `echo` the line that found string specified.
- After `/n` option, we specify string that should be searched in specified after file.
- After that, we specify the file we want to search the specified string.

The syntax is quite similar, but the output is **completely different**!:

```bat
---------- %FILENAME_SPECIFIED_WITH_CAPITAL_LETTERS%
[%line_number%]%line_content%
```

So, here:

- We ignore lines starting with `-` with `eol=-` option.
- We don't parse `[]` symbols into tokens with `delims=[]`.
- We want to access `line_number` with `%(%)A` and `line_content` with `%(%)B`, so, we add `tokens=1,2` option.
- Then, continuing as above (well known).

For better understanding how these commands work, I suggest you to open a new cmd window and type:

- `for /?`
- `find /?`
- `findstr /?`

Try some examples of yours with `find` and `finstr` to completely understand how they work.

Some interesting references for further reading:

- https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/find.html